# Parse csv data and convert to nested json java

Tags: java, json, csv, jar

I'm searching for simplest way or any jar available to read csv file in java and convert to into nested json. I tried searching for various sources, but all the places i could find results for simple json, but my need is i should read csv file which later has to be converted to json string in the below format

```
{
    "studentName": "Foo",
    "Age": "12",
    "address":{
        "city" : "newyork",
        "address1": "North avenue",
        "zipcode" : "123213"
    },
    "subjects": [
        {
            "name": "English",
            "marks": "40"
        },
        {
            "name": "History",
            "marks": "50"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm fine with any format in csv, however after reading csv file i need to create json string like above.

csv file format:

```
"studentName","Age","address__city","address__address1","address__zipcode","subjects__name","subjects__marks"
"Foo","12","newyork","North avenue","123213","English","40"
"","","","","","History","50"
```

Comment: Have you tried openCSV? I cannot supply you a link at the moment because they're migrating to a new datacenter, but they have a CSV parser

Comment: Can you provide and example of the CSV data you will be parsing as how the nested address and subject will influence the solution

Comment: The answer to this is "use a JSON library" (or "use a CSV library", depending on which of the two halves of the question you answer) -- and because of that, it's effectively an off-topic "Please recommend a library" question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JackSon` to convert `CSV` to `JSON`. For example see the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

public class CSV2JSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File input = new File("input.csv");
        File output = new File("output.json");

        CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.builder().setUseHeader(true).build();
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

        // Read data from CSV file
        List<object> readAll = csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class).with(csvSchema).readValues(input).readAll();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Write JSON formated data to output.json file
        mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(output, readAll);

        // Write JSON formated data to stdout
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(readAll));
    }
}
```

If you are using `maven` you can add the `Jackson` dependency as following:

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.9</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.9</version>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: is this will work any type of csv format ? can you tell me the format of csv to have nested json string as output.

Comment: im getting below exception when i tried in reverese way.. json to csv. 
 JsonMappingException: CSV generator does not support Object values for properties (through reference chain: csvparser.User["address"])

Comment: This code cannot read the CSV sample as the JSON sample given in the question. It does not bother nesting the objects. It simply converts the CSV to that: (only the 1st row is shown below for simplicity) 
{
  "studentName" : "Foo",
  "Age" : "12",
  "address__city" : "newyork",
  "address__address1" : "North avenue",
  "address__zipcode" : "123213",
  "subjects__name" : "English",
  "subjects__marks" : "40"
}

Comment: Not a solution for the question asked.